# Changing Only Color of Equations and Not Tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, equations, color

I change the color of the equations using the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{blue}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
$inside\;math$
\begin{equation}
    inside\;math\;equation
\end{equation}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    inside tabular
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The color of the equations changes, but that also changes the color of the tables and some lines in Tikz images. What did I do wrong? And how to keep everything else from changing color?

## Edit

Based on @DavidCarlisle answer, here is a workaround for the problem of changing color inside the $...$ signs, which is to redefine them as \(...\). 
Improvements and corrections are more than welcome.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

% change color inside equation environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{blue}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{blue}}
% change color of math inside \(...\) and \[...\]
\AddToHook{cmd/(/after}{\color{blue}}
\AddToHook{cmd/[/after}{\color{blue}}

% redefine $...$ as \(...\)
\begingroup
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\gdef$#1${\(#1\)}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=\active}


\begin{document}

A possible trick is to change all $\$\;math\;\$$ to \(\setminus(math\setminus)\).
\begin{equation}
    inside\;math\;equation
\end{equation}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    inside tabular
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Changing color inside math mode]

Comment: Please post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: I do not see anything related except for these three lines. The preamble and style are quite long ones, otherwise, I would post them.

Comment: If you do not make them short, who should make them short? As it is now, many people will feel that the effort to help you is too big. If you really want help, make it easy to help you.

Comment: use `\begin{tabular}[t]`

Comment: math mode is used in lots of places, including vertically centred tables and minipages If you use a primitive `\everymath` you color them all.

Comment: @mickep First of all, I already made it short. Second, I am looking for someone who can solve the problem given the three lines or who can guide me to extract the relevant code, which I still believe is not relevant. It is a really big document and the issue is not urgent for me. I posted the question for someone who came across the same issue, solved it, and now can provide a helpful answer for me and other people as a reference. If you cannot help, please pass.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to change color only inside `\begin{equation}`?

Comment: Really you should provide a small test file, why expect everyone making an answer to have to make a test file?

Comment: You show how to do it for equation in your question, you can do similar for `align` etc.  also `\(....\)`  doing it for just `$....$` that are "really" math is harder

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited the question for the sake of your mastery. The three lines are the relevant code. You are right, I know how to do it for equations, the problem is that I don't want the color to bleed into the tables.

Comment: as  say, use `[t]` for tabular is easiest, or remove `\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}} `  and add color to other math environments as for equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\everymath` catches all internal math mode including most vertically centred constructs such as `tabular`, `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}


\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{blue}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{blue}}
\AddToHook{cmd/(/after}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\(inside\;math\)
\begin{equation}
    inside\;math\;equation
\end{equation}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    inside tabular
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```