# `\vv` is not respecting the current color

Tags: color

How to make `\vv`, from the esvect package, respect the current color after using `\everymath`

Example:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor, amsmath, esvect}

\begin{document}

\everymath{\color{blue}}
\(\color{red} \vv{F} \text{ red}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). With just `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xcolor, amsmath, esvect}` I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you, I just noticed that it was caused by the use of `\everymath`

Comment: Just a guess, but the `\vv` macro probably uses `\ensuremath` or some similar macro to make sure that its output is in math mode, thereby adding some kind of hook to the output which `\everymath` uses to insert `\color{blue}` to the group, which again is why `\vv{F}` is printed in blue. You will probably run into the same problem with other math macros as well.

Comment: @JasperHabicht ok thank you, but is there a way around this behaviour please ?

Comment: don't use `\everymath{\color{blue}}` if you do not want all math use to be blue, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660406/1090

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `\everymath{\color{blue}}` if you do not want all math use to be blue, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660406/1090

From @david-carlisle